# Flex:programmatically selecting some row - selectedItem is null

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

In my application, I have a datagrid that is bound to RemoteObject.  The 
datagrid has a corresponding form that contains the details.  When 
the user clicks on a row in the datagrid the form populates with the 
values from the DataGrid's selectedItem.

I want to programatically select some row in my DataGrid when 
the application loads.

In order to do this, I have to call validateNow() and scrollToIndex()

eg.

dg.selectedIndex = i; 
dg.validateNow();
dg.scrollToIndex(i);

I put this code in the Applications creationComplete handler.

This all works great - the desired row is highlighted and selected and 
the selectedIndex is i.  The problem is that I can't access the data 
to populate the details form.  When I try to retrieve the 
dg.SelectedItem property - it is null.

How does one programatically select some row in the grid on load 
AND access the row data?

thanks

Answer (score 8):

use

```
dg.invalidateList();
dg.callLater(setRows, [1]);

function selRows(indices:Array):void {
  dg.selectedIndices = indices;
  dg.validateNow();
  dg.scrollToRow(indices[0]);
}
```

Basically if you are changing DG data and selecting an item in the same flow, your seleciton will be overwritten by ListBase methods, you have to set the selections after current GUI update for which you need to use callLater methoad.

Comment: This is great! I had a similar problem (datagrid selection reset upon provider change) where I needed to store the selected items before the data changes and update them again when the change is over and it didn't work until I used your callLater solution. 10x!

Answer (score 0):

the selected item of the datagrid is just pointing to the item in the dataProvider. If you know which item you want selected in your datagrid, just use that item in your source data to do the initial population of your form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy.But the dataProvider is also null.I can not do this:datagrid.dataProvider[i] or something